# Laravel - Eloquent Search on Join but returning multiple rows, need one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have two models `Product` and `ProductPriceHistories`

`Product` hasMany `ProductPriceHistories` and it's basically a daily price of a product.

I have one slight problem, when I try to find the lowest price of the product I'm returned multiple of the same `products` because of the join finding multiple prices for the product.

This is my query:

```
$products = ProductPriceHistory::orderBy(
                'product_price_histories.price',
                $request->get('direction')
            )
            ->with('products')
            ->select('products.*')
            ->paginate(16);
```

I have tried various ways, but essentially I need to get the products in the order of most expensive or cheapest based on `$request->get('direction')`

If it's not possible to do it in Eloquent I will do it in a DB:Raw but surely it's me not knowing how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a closure to every element in the `with()` method where you can order the eager loaded products and even, as you mentioned, get only the first one:

```
->with(['products' => function($query) use ($request)
{
    $query->orderBy('orderByColumn', $request->get('direction'))
        ->first();  // If you want only the first result
}])
```

Hope this helps you.